# How to install a network driver for Ethernet adapter in Ubuntu 20.04.4?

Tags: networking, drivers, server, ethernet, adapter

I have set up a dedicated Ubuntu server using a game management panel called "PufferPanel" to host a Minecraft server (so no GUI). I recently bought this [USB to RJ-45](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00MYT481C) network adapter after the one in my computer stopped working. However, the adapter doesn't work as "plug and play" and I get the dreaded msg: "waiting for network to be configured".

Conversely, I was able to get the network connected in Windows so I figured out that it was a driver issue. There is a CD disk and a USB thumb drive with the linux drivers included.

I am only a novice in working with linux so I want to whether it is possible to install the drivers in my server, if so how?

Comment: Your link specifies "*It requires installing the driver on ... and Linux, which you can easily install with our instructions.*" Did you contact the vendor for those instructions?

Comment: @user535733 It came with a manual but the instructions on it are very generic and only applies for an OS with a GUI. 
Link to see for yourself: https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0257/5246/9566/files/CR110_20253_20254_20257.pdf?v=1624261710
Maybe I should get another one that works right out of the box?

Comment: Okay I was finally able to get the ethernet to work after completely reinstalling the server and updating to the latest version of Ubuntu.